# Strange compile error with lifetime notation: "expected `:`, found `>`"

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, lexer

I have defined a struct and method like so:

```
struct Lexer<'a> {
    input: String,
    pos: CharIndices<'a>,
    next_pos: Peekable<CharIndices<'a>>,
    ch: char,
}

impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    pub fn new(input: String) -> Lexer<'a> {
        let mut lexer = Lexer<'a> {
            input,
            pos: input.char_indices(),
            next_pos: input.char_indices().peekable(),
            ch: char::from(0 as u8),
        };

        lexer
    }
}
```

When compiling I get the error

```
error: expected `:`, found `>`
  --> src/lexer/mod.rs:15:33
   |
15 |         let mut lexer = Lexer<'a> {
   |                                 ^ expected `:`
```

However, doing as it asks and changing the offending line to `let mut lexer = Lexer<'a:> {` makes no sense and recompiling confirms that this is indeed incorrect.

```
error: expected `while`, `for`, `loop` or `{` after a label
  --> src/lexer/mod.rs:15:34
   |
15 |         let mut lexer = Lexer<'a:> {
   |                                  ^ expected `while`, `for`, `loop` or `{` after a label
```

I'm not sure why the compiler is complaining and as best I can tell the lifetime notation looks fine to me.

[Rust Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb7cc6831c6917d7ef15dbb1362b655a)

Comment: Your code does not compile, because `0` is not a char and this question is just a syntactic error. You would have to write `Lexer::<'a>` or shorter `Lexer` (also this is not an MCVE, because you could omit all the fields from `Lexer` and just add something that needs `<'a>`, e.g. [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html))

Comment: `Lexer<'a` can be the beginning of an expression comparing a variable named `Lexer` to a named loop expression like `'a: loop { break 'a 4; }`. [Example](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a83eebeb97f0cdca1a09e8c72ef5ee93)

Comment: @hellow 0 is not a char but the compiler doesn't give an error for that until after the error in question has been resolved so I did not catch it. There are (many) other errors with this code, but none can be seen by the compiler until error in question is fixed. I have updated my question regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just realized, there is no need for a lifetime on the constructor.

The correct notation is

```
let mut lexer = Lexer {
```

not

```
let mut lexer = Lexer<'a> {
```

Comment: and why `mut` ? ;)

Comment: There is no need in the code as is. In my actual program lexer is modified after being constructed but before being returned. I removed it for the question as it was irrelevant. I will update my code here to better reflect that.

Comment: that was obvious don't worry ^^